# Widget test with Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a widget test to ensure my widget is being correctly displayed. My app is using Firebase and this particular widget is using Firebase Storage to access a user's profile photos. I'm using this [package](https://github.com/atn832/firebase_storage_mocks) as recommended by [Flutter docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/testing/testing/#unit-tests-using-fakes), however it seems as though either the storage mock isn't working as expected or I'm not allowing the widget to populate itself correctly. I think it's the latter but not entirely sure.

Here is my test (test/widget_test/file_to_test.dart):

```
testWidgets('Profile screen displays proper data', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final mockUserRepo = MockUserRepository();
    FirebaseStorage storage = MockFirebaseStorage();

    final imageZeroRef = storage.ref().child("123/image-0.jpg");
    final fileZero = await rootBundle.load("../../assets/Welcome.png");
    final res = await imageZeroRef.putData(fileZero.buffer.asUint8List());
    Logger().i(res.ref.bucket); // prints "some-bucket" which is apparently hard-coded by the package

    await tester.pumpWidget(ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        userProvider.overrideWith((ref) {
          return mockUserRepo;
        }),
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: UserProfileScreen(),
      ),
    ));

    await tester.pump(); // Have tried pumpAndSettle, adding a duration, and even multiple pump calls

    final firstNameFinder = find.text("Bob, 27");
    expect(firstNameFinder, findsOneWidget); // Test fails here

    final aboutFinder = find.text("About Bob");
    expect(aboutFinder, findsOneWidget);
});
```

I also have a mocked out repository which is calling this method

```
Future<List<String>> getUserImages(String userId) async {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: "gs://some-bucket");
    final storageRef = storage.ref();

    try {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        final imageRef = storageRef.child("$userId/image-$i.jpg");
        final downloadUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        userImages[i] = downloadUrl;
      }

      return userImages;
    } on FirebaseException catch (err, stackTrace) {
      Logger().e("unable to download profile images for user with id $userId \n Error Code: ${err.code} \n Error Message: ${err.message} \n $stackTrace");
    }

    return userImages;
  }
```

**Edit: Widget being tested**

```
class UserProfileScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const UserProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<UserProfileScreen> createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}

class _UserProfileScreenState extends ConsumerState<UserProfileScreen> {
  bool haveSentInvite = false;
  bool inviteFriendSuccess = false;
  List<String> userImages = ['', '', '', '', '', ''];

  int determineUserAge(DateTime date) {
    final DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.parse(date.toString());
    final DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
    final age = currentDate.difference(parsedDate);
    final ageInYears = age.inDays / 365;
    return ageInYears.floor();
  }

  Future<List<String>> getUserImages(String userId) async {
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: "gs://bucket-name").ref(); // Have tried setting this to "some-bucket"

    try {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        final imageRef = storageRef.child("$userId/image-$i.jpg");
        final downloadUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        userImages[i] = downloadUrl;
      }
      return userImages;
    } on FirebaseException catch (err, stackTrace) {
      Logger().e("unable to download profile images for user with id $userId \n Error Code: ${err.code} \n Error Message: ${err.message} \n $stackTrace");
    }

    return userImages;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserRepository authUser = ref.watch(userProvider);
    UserRepository user = UserRepository(userId: authUser.userId);
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;

    if (args != null) {
      user = args as UserRepository;

      return FutureBuilder(
          future: Future.wait([
            user.fetchUserData(FirebaseFirestore.instance, user.userId),
            user.checkFriends(FirebaseFirestore.instance, authUser.userId, user.userId),
          ]),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                user.user = snapshot.data?[0];
                return buildPage(context, authUser, user, snapshot.data?[1], true);
              default:
                return buildLoadingPage();
            }
          });
    } else {
      return buildPage(context, authUser, null, null, false);
    }
  }

  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, UserRepository authUser, UserRepository? viewUser, FriendRequest? friendRequest, bool fromArgs) {
    String userId = viewUser == null ? authUser.userId : viewUser.userId;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getUserImages(userId),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
            return ListView(
              cacheExtent: 1000,
              children: [
                userImages[0] != ""
                    ? ImageCard(
                        imageUrl: userImages[0],
                        text: viewUser != null ? "${viewUser.user?.firstName}, ${determineUserAge(viewUser.user!.birthdate!)}" : "${authUser.user?.firstName}, ${determineUserAge(authUser.user!.birthdate!)}",
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                Card(
                  elevation: 0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                  ),
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 30),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        TitleText(
                          title: "About",
                          text: viewUser != null ? "${viewUser.user?.about}" : "${authUser.user?.about}",
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                userImages[1] != "" ? ImageCard(imageUrl: userImages[1]) : const SizedBox(),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                userImages[2] != "" ? ImageCard(imageUrl: userImages[2]) : const SizedBox(),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                userImages[3] != "" ? ImageCard(imageUrl: userImages[3]) : const SizedBox(),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                userImages[4] != "" ? ImageCard(imageUrl: userImages[4]) : const SizedBox(),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                userImages[5] != "" ? ImageCard(imageUrl: userImages[5]) : const SizedBox(),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      appBar: LeiferAppBar(showLeading: true),
      bottomNavigationBar: fromArgs
          ? Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 25.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                    width: 60.0,
                    child: determineFriendButton(context, mounted, friendRequest, authUser, viewUser),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          : const SizedBox(
              width: 0.0,
              height: 0.0,
            ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildLoadingPage() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 250,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 35),
              const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 35),
              const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "About Me",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 102, 203, 1)),
                ),
              ),
              const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const SizedBox(
        width: 0.0,
        height: 0.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget determineFriendButton(BuildContext context, bool mounted, FriendRequest? friendRequest, UserRepository authUser, UserRepository? viewUser) {
    switch (friendRequest?.status) {
      case "accepted":
        return PopupMenuButton(
          onSelected: (dynamic item) async {
            await authUser.removeFriend(FirebaseFirestore.instance, friendRequest!.friendRequestId);
            if (mounted) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
            child: const Icon(Icons.check),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<dynamic>>[
            const PopupMenuItem<dynamic>(
              value: "remove",
              child: Text("Remove Friend"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      case "pending":
        if (friendRequest?.sourceUserId == authUser.userId) {
          return PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (dynamic item) async {
              await authUser.removeFriend(FirebaseFirestore.instance, friendRequest!.friendRequestId);
              if (mounted) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              ),
              child: const Icon(Icons.question_mark),
            ),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<dynamic>>[
              const PopupMenuItem<dynamic>(
                value: "remove",
                child: Text("Cancel Request"),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
        return PopupMenuButton(
          onSelected: (dynamic item) async {
            await authUser.respondToFriendRequest(FirebaseFirestore.instance, friendRequest!.friendRequestId, item);
            if (mounted) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
            child: const Icon(Icons.question_mark),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<dynamic>>[
            const PopupMenuItem<dynamic>(
              value: "accepted",
              child: Text("Confirm"),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<dynamic>(
              value: "declined",
              child: Text("Delete"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      default:
        return IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final res = await viewUser?.addFriend(FirebaseFirestore.instance, authUser.userId);
            setState(() {
              haveSentInvite = true;
              res == 200 ? inviteFriendSuccess = true : false;
            });
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.person_add_outlined),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: since this is a widget test question, please include the widget being tested for more context.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele no problem, just updated